# Confused with user management in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a WPF application that connects to a SQL Server database directly (not through services), located on database server. Now I need to create user management, where each user will have its own log in credentials (not windows authentication). This is how I thought of doing it:

1. During the application installation, DB administrator will provide me with an account that contains enough permissions to create database
2. Using these credentials I will connect to SQL Server, execute a script to create database, and also execute a script to create one default admin user for this database, that will have full permissions.
3. I will use this new user to manage all users and roles for my database.
4. for each user in my application I need to create a user in my database.

Questions:

- is this correct way of doing it?
- I am confused about how to manage this. If I have a table Users and Roles in my database, and I also need to create users and roles on database level, then it looks like I am duplicating stuff?

Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only very minor overlap.  In your Users table you store the username that matches up with the SQL account, the username is the only overlap.  All other information is stored in the Users table.

I don't see any problem with doing it this way, the only downside is that you are required to have an admin account with a considerable amount of access on whatever SQL Server it's installed on, but it sounds like you have already taken that into consideration.

Comment: Well, I do not see any other way to install application and create database, if no login credentials are provided? If you know of any, please share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it differently by creating roles and managing things through roles rather than user names/logins. 
It would be better to create one application login in Database, whose credentials will be used for communication between your DB and application.

Comment: Well, I do have roles. But if I have only one user that connects to database, how would I provide credentials for this user? Where would I store it?

Comment: What i mean is, it is better to have only one DB login name which should talk to your database. In your Service/Business layer you may handle access levels of the logged in user. Plus, you store roles, user names in tables of your database.

Comment: Forgot to mention. You do NOT need to create users and roles on database level. Just add these new users and roles into table as records. There is NO need to add them separately to your Database Management though GUI or script.

Comment: Ok. But where would I keep this "one-for-all" username and password?

Comment: In config file. You may also encrypt it, if security is concern.

Comment: This is the problem - security! I cannot hide anything, since anyone can peak into the code, and see what kind of encryption I am using, and use the same method to access encrypted password.

Comment: Well, you may have different config files per environment, with different passwords in it. This may partially reduce the risk. Or you need to switch on windows authentication.

Comment: I cannot switch to windows authentication, since I need multiple users to login from the same PC/User. It doesnt matter if I hab=ve multiple config files, the code that will be doing login is in c#, so it can be easily extracted, and easy to retrieve the password.

Comment: Your user/password credentials are NOT going to be saved in c#. Your application will read/check user credentials from DB tables. However your connection to the database is provided through connection string. Does this answer your question ?

Comment: No, its still not clear. Lets say that I have a database user called 'mike', and password '123'. This is a "one-for-all" user, it doesnt have anything to do with my table Users and Roles. This is what you suggest. How will I provide in my connection string user and password credentials, so I can connect to database?

Comment: And this username and password I need to use in connection string, right? In order to do that, I need to store it somewhere, so I can read it.

Comment: I think you understood differently, what i was trying to explain. You need to create one DB login per application. For example: 1)"baseballapplication" as username and password "123456" in database. 2) Add this in your configuration <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=baseball_app;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=baseballapplication;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  ... Then reference the connection string to talk to your DB. So, u are using Only one DB login per application.Hope this will help

Comment: For your question, i provided connection string where you store it to be used in application. And you need to create "baseballapplication" login in your database, let say called "baseball_app". Hope it is clear now.

Comment: It was clear from the beginning. So, if I am a malicious user, and open config file, see the connection string. and write few lines of code that will create a connection with specified connection string, and execute this query: DELETE * FROM Customers.... I will then delete all records in this table, since I know the credentials that I can use to connect to database. So, my original question - where is the security here?

Comment: Goran, this is a totally different question, i think you will agree on this. You may Google "how to secure connection string in visual studio". You will get a number of options to go with. Thanks for voting!

Comment: From my point of view it is quite connected. This is the actual reason why I wanted to go with several DB users, and not just one, so a user would always need to provide username and password. You, on the other hand said that I should store credentials on the client PC, which is the reason why I didn't want to go with one user only. What you suggested is quite common for web applications, where client never connects to Db directly. In this case, it is a intranet application that connects to DB directly (no services involved), and I don't know any secure way to save credentials on the client PC

Comment: Your db connection info needs to be in your server side. Are you using smart client architecture?

Comment: It cannot be on the server side, since this application is not using services, but is connecting to database directly.